# Command + Tab Not Working on Fullscreen Apps When Finder Is Active

Tags: keyboard, finder, shortcut

I have recently upgraded to MacOS Catalina, and since then, this problem started.

Every time I attempt to switch between programs using the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, *only when currently viewing a Desktop / having Finder as active application*, switching fails. Same goes for using the similar Spotlight Search method of <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and typing the desired open program. Clicking the program in the Dock works, but it's relatively tedious to do.

I've already tried `killall Dock` multiple times. [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227086/finder-spotlight-shortcut-and-commandtab-switching-apps-stopped-working) question seems to come close, but I *can* summon the '<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> list' and Spotlight bar – they just don't *switch* applications. Help!